# How can I import a VMDK disk image to an AWS EC2 t2.micro instance on us-east-1e region using an S3 bucket on us-east-1?

Tags: virtual-machine, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've recently purchased a reserved EC2 micro instance on region eu-east-1e.

I am having trouble importing a virtual machine using ec2-api-tools:

```
ec2iin -t t2.micro "CentOS 7 x86_64-disk1.vmdk" -g my-launch-config -f VMDK -a x86_64 -p Linux 
-b mybucket -o MYID -w MYSECRETKEY +A -s 10 
-d importingMinimalCentos764VMDK --region us-east-1e --subnet mysubnetid
```

output:

```
Requesting volume size: 10 GB
ERROR: Unable to create signed manifest URL. Cannot access/create bucket: mybucket : com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException
: Unable to execute HTTP request: mybucket.s3.us-east-1e.amazonaws.com
```

Which makes sense since the address of my bucket is `mybucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`, but if I choose that region then I get a different error:

```
Client.InvalidParameter: Subnet 'mysubnetid' is in the availability zone 'us-east-1e'. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status
Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 6e6d886f-2932-42f8-b771-b99475371bc6)
```

If I keep the region us-east-1 and ommit the `--subnet mysubnetid` then I still got a problem, since apparently I cannot create a t2.micro on us-east-1:

```
Client.Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported
 configurations. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: Unsupported; Request ID: 91fe5c48-2a0e-45bc-90fb-d7a
581fc3780)
```

There is no way to create a bucket on us-east-1e region. It is not listed and the command line tool `aws s3 mb s3://mybucket --region us-east-1e` gives an `error, region not found` when I try.

How can I fix this? I just want to upload and convert my VMDK to launch the t2.micro I've reserved and I need a bucket on the same region for that! I suppose I can do it in another region, then crate an image, then move the image to my desired region. But will I be able to export any changes to that instance? (when I tried to export an image before I got an error like `you can only export imported instances`, that's why I am creating a VMDK VM and importing it: so I can export it later, anytime I want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first: regions like `us-east-1` contain availability zones like `us-east-1e`. S3 operates in terms of regions, whereas many EC2 concepts (including VPC subnets and reserved instances) are specifically concerned with availability zones.

The [ec2-import-instance documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ImportInstance.html) shows how to specify both a region and an availability zone. Try `--region us-east-1 --availability-zone us-east-1e`.