# Unable to import my vmdk to EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vmdk

I am trying to import my *vmdk* to EC2 as a instance using S3 bucket
I am using this syntax

```
ec2-user@ip-10-0-x-x ~$ ec2-import-instance disk1.vmdk -f VMDK -t m1.xlarge -a x86_64 -b import-raj -o XXXXXXACCESS KEY -w XXXXXXXSECRETKEY -O ACESSKEYXXXXXXX -W SECRETKEYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Requesting volume size: 90 GB  
ERROR: Unable to create signed manifest URL. Bucket import-raj is not in us-east-1 region, it's in eu-west-1
```

Can you please provide me the exact syntax to be used

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests you are not in the correct region.

According to the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ImportInstance.html) you need to specify a zone. You do this with the option flag `-z zonename`. In your instance I think it would be `-z eu-west-1`, I am not familiar enough with the Amazon platform to confirm the zone.

According to [further research](https://superuser.com/a/846891/393570) in addition to specifying the zone you need to specify a region as well using `--region`. Again I am not familiar with the regions available, you would have to check these for your needs.

The full command would look like this:

```
ec2-import-instance disk1.vmdk -f VMDK -t m1.xlarge -a x86_64 -z eu-west-1 --region eu-west-1 -b import-raj -o XXXXXXACCESS KEY -w XXXXXXXSECRETKEY -O ACESSKEYXXXXXXX -W SECRETKEYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

From the documentation for setting a zone:

> `-z, --availability-zone` *`availability_zone`*
>
> The Availability Zone for the converted VM.
>
> Type: String
>
> Valid values: Use ec2-describe-availability-zones for a list of values
>
> Default: None
>
> Required: No
>
> Example: `-z us-east-1a`

From the documentation for setting a region:

> `--region` *`region`*
>
> The region. Overrides the default region, the region specified by the `EC2_URL` environment variable, and the URL specified by the `-U` option.
>
> Default: The region specified by the `EC2_URL` environment variable, or `us-east-1` if `EC2_URL` isn't set.

Comment: ec2-import-instance disk1.vmdk -f VMDK -t m1.xlarge -a x86_64 -z eu-west-1 -b import-raj -o Accesskey -w secret key -O access key -W secret key
Requesting volume size: 90 GB
ERROR: Unable to create signed manifest URL. Bucket import-raj is not in us-east-1 region, it's in eu-west-1   ,still the same result.

Comment: You may need to have a look at the `--region region` command as well.